# GeoFire Firebase Query not able to Store userID in ArrayList

Tags: java, android, firebase, geofire

I am using GeoFire to get all users with in a certain radius. When I the addGeoQueryEventListener & then use a for loop to get all the user id, instead of returning the UserID it goes another nest deeper returning g and 1.

```
private int radius = 40;
private Boolean userFound = false;
private String userLocationID;
private ArrayList<String> mUserIDLocation;
final UserLocation userLocation = new UserLocation();
public void getUserLocation() {

    mUserIDLocation = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling

        return;
    }
    fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener((Activity) MainActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {

            if (location != null) {
                //Toast.makeText(this, "UserLocation " + location.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                //final Location userLocation = location;
                Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: UserLocation" + location);
                Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: UserLocation Latitude " + location.getLatitude());

                String user_id = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
                final DatabaseReference mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

                final GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(mRef.child("user_location"));
                geoFire.setLocation(user_id, new GeoLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });

                GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), radius);


                geoQuery.addGeoQueryDataEventListener(new GeoQueryDataEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataEntered(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, GeoLocation location) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onDataEntered: DataSnapshot Key " + dataSnapshot);

                        for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                            mFollowing.add(snapshot.getKey());
                        }

                        getPost();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onDataEntered: mFollowing " + mFollowing);
                        Log.d(TAG, "onDataEntered: mFollowing size " + mFollowing.size());

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onDataExited(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onDataMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, GeoLocation location) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onDataChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, GeoLocation location) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onGeoQueryReady() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

}
```

**Log for database snapshot:**

onDataEntered: DataSnapshot Key DataSnapshot { key = xjfXxJ3spuPNywtHyqg5rNnlIMD3, value = {.priority=c295tcm4kd, l={0=48.435, 1=-122.084}, g=c295tcm4kd} }

onDataEntered: DataSnapshot Key DataSnapshot { key = TMOb5NL8igZovGkiZdVcl3UQmxV2, value = {.priority=c295myvnsd, l={0=48.4319983, 1=-122.084}, g=c295myvnsd} }

**Log for what is add to mFollowing ArrayList:**
onDataEntered: mFollowing [g, l]
onDataEntered: mFollowing [g, l, g, l]

**Log for size of mFollowing ArrayList:**
onDataEntered: mFollowing size 2
onDataEntered: mFollowing size 4

**A picture of my database:**
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPdVz.png)

What I expect to happen is the userID are added to the mFollowing and when I run the log for mFollowing, I only see 2 userID in the array and the count to be 2.

Comment: Each `dataSnapshot` in `onDataEntered` is a user so just use `dataSnapshot.getKey` to add to `mFollowing`.

Comment: But that is not what your code is doing - you are descending one level with the "children" loop - nix that.

Comment: You would think but when I do it your way and use `mFollowing.size()` in another method `for( int i = 0; i < mFollowing.size(); i++){ //insert code} ` I get a size that looks like 1, 2, 2 instead of just 2. Does the same thing with the userIDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out the problem. `OnDataEntered()` is a loop that checks all users in the area. So you store all the users in one Arraylist and then pass them to another array list in `OnGeoQueryReady()`

Below is the correct code.

```
    private int radius = 40;
    private Boolean userFound = false;
    private String userLocationID;
    private ArrayList<String> mUserIDLocation;
    final UserLocation userLocation = new UserLocation();
    public void getUserLocation() {
        final DatabaseReference mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        final GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(mRef.child("user_location"));
        mUserIDLocation = new ArrayList<String>();

        swipe.setRefreshing(false);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling

            return;
        }
        fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener((Activity) MainActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {

                if (location != null) {
                    //Toast.makeText(this, "UserLocation " + location.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                    //final Location userLocation = location;
                    Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: UserLocation" + location);
                    Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: UserLocation Latitude " + location.getLatitude());

                    String user_id = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();




                    geoFire.setLocation(user_id, new GeoLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {

                        }
                    });

                    GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), radius);


                    geoQuery.addGeoQueryDataEventListener(new GeoQueryDataEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataEntered(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, GeoLocation location) {

                            Log.d(TAG, "onDataEntered: datasnapshot " + dataSnapshot);

                            mUserIDLocation.add(dataSnapshot.getKey());


                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDataExited(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDataMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, GeoLocation location) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDataChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, GeoLocation location) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onGeoQueryReady() {

                            mFollowing = mUserIDLocation;

                            Log.d(TAG, "onGeoQueryReady: mFollowing users " + mFollowing);

                            getPost();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Now the array size will be correct when `mFollowing` is passed to `getPost()`